# Getting Over Struct Implementation in Swift

Tags: arrays, class, swift, struct

In Swift, everything is implemented as a struct rather than a class. Values are being passed in, but the memory address does not store them. Here is an example:

```
import UIKit


var array = Array<Int>()
array = [6,2,9,1,10,4,9,3,5,8,7]
let count = array.count

func insertSort(var arr : Array<Int>)->(){
for(var i = 1; i<arr.count-1; i++){
    var j : Int
    for( j = i; j > 0; j--){
        if(arr[j]<arr[j-1]){
            var temp = arr[j-1]
            var temp2 = arr[j]
            arr.removeAtIndex(j-1)
            arr.insert(temp2, atIndex: j-1)
            arr.removeAtIndex(j)
            arr.insert(temp, atIndex: j)
        }
    }
}
for item in arr{
    print(item)
}
}

insertSort(array)

array
```

I know that this isn't the most concise way to implement an insertion sort, but I was just trying to use the most Swift I could.

My issue: through the `print` statement in the function, I can see that the algorithm works - the list is returned sorted. However, when I print the array at the bottom, Playground returns the same array as the one I declared at the top, ie unsorted. I know why that is (the array is not implemented as a class), I just wanted to know if there is a way to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

To modify a value type passed to a function, you need to pass it as an `inout` parameter:

```
func insertSort(inout arr: [Int]) {
    // etc.
}

insertSort(&array)
```

This is how `Swift.sort` is declared – try cmd-opt-clicking it in a playground or take a look at the [Swifter](http://swiftdoc.org/func/sort/) docs.

`inout` should be used *sparingly* – one of the big benefits of structs is that they can be declared immutable with `let`, but immutable structs cannot be passed as `inout` parameters.  This is why the standard library declares both `sort`, which takes an inout and sorts in-place, and `sorted`, which takes input by value and returns a freshly sorted array.

Comment: Thanks! Of course I would normally use the given sort, but if it's like Java (mergesort) then I may want to use a faster sorting algorithm depending on the input.

Comment: Swift’s sort is as of 1.1 an [introsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort) (which is a hybrid between a quicksort and a heapsort), but with insertion sort for small input ranges.  This is as shown by sticking a breakpoint on a custom less-than operator, but it’s undocumented so not guaranteed to stay this way.  The docs do state it’s unstable, which would have made merge sort unlikely.